# Cant find local Win XP network from MacBook Pro on Wlan / Lan is OK on Snow Leopard 10.6.4

Tags: windows-xp, macbook, networking, wireless-networking, airport-express

Can't find my local windows pc's from my Macbook Pro with wlan. 
// Lan is working fine, all local networking Win XP PC's are listed in Finder!
I use Airport Express in Bridge mode. No other result in other modes.
Airport is connected with lan to my router as a Wlan access point for my macbook Pro. (Snow leo 10.6.4)
When i remove the lan cable from the Airport Express device and connect it to my macbook everthing works fine. But if i put it back in the Airport and go with wlan, i can reach the internet but none of the other local Win computers. I tried differtent configurations on my Airport but had only succes for a few minutes can find and use all Printers etc. connected to that win computers, after a while 3-5 minutes or so, all win PC's are disapearing from my finder.Used xhttp://manuals.info.apple.com/en_US/Designing_AirPort_Networks_10.5-Windows.pdf
does not realy helped me to solve this.

+Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

Well as far i found out i have to connect to the Win PC's with W-Lan by hand.
Means Finder  ⌘ K Key (connect to Server) type the ip of the Win PC you want to ad.
Decide acces as guest or as user (User and password req) and thats it.

Hope someone can explain when lan kable is in use you get the names of the local PC's and in W-lan you have to ad them by hand.

Hope this help somebody out there.. Sorry for my still misserable english. But as a russian spy you want learn english very well ;)